# Response of REST (POST via Powershell) is not complete

Tags: rest, powershell, response

I'm started working with the Invoke-RestMethod of Powershell and have now the probleme that the responses I got after my POST to the REST API of our Monitoring Tool is not complete. If I'am using other tools like a REST extension for the browser I got much more feedback:

**Response REST Extension Webbrowser:**

```
{
   "entry": [
      {
         "@datatype": "int",
         "@name": "CheckTime",
         "value": {
            "@type": "xs:int",
            "$": "1542802849"
         }
      },
      {
         "@datatype": "int",
         "@name": "AvailPageFile",
         "value": {
            "@type": "xs:int",
            "$": "12345"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Response Powershell Invoke-RestMethod:**

```
entry
-----
@{@datatype=int; @name=CheckTime; value=} @{@datatype=int; @name=AvailPageFile; value=}
```

so the 2nd Level of {} after Value= is missing.

Here is my Code:

```
$username = "user"
$password = "password"
$url = "http://urlREST"

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($username):$($password)")); 
    "Accept" = 'application/json ';
}


$data = @{}
$body = ConvertTo-Json $data

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $body
```

Does somebody have a tipp for me?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that there are dozens of other PowerShell JSON serialization questions with one common cause: [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) has a `-Depth` parameter that defaults to **`2`**.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically getting the same response but it is inside a PSobject. Try the following:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $body
```

Now play around with the $response parameter such as:

```
$response.entry
$response.entry.name
```

Etcetera. Also do a:

```
$response.gettype()
```

To learn more about PowerShell objects. If this still does not give you the right information, search for responseStream and how to get it!

Comment: `$response | Format-List *`

Comment: Thanks Bernard, for your answer. That directly solve my problem. And also thanks for the keyword "responseStream". I was already reading a lot of information about the invoke command, but with the wrong keywords I wasn't able to find a solution.